# Did King kill any monster in the webcomic out of fear?

Tags: one-punch-man

In One Punch Man manga #111 ,

A monster so tense for the fear of being killed by King, unintentionally destroyed his internal organs and died.

Did King kill any monster in the webcomic out of fear like he did in the manga?

Comment: There is no chapter 151 in the manga. Latest is Chapter 111, AFAIK: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_One-Punch_Man_chapters

Comment: oops 111.......

Comment: I'd have to re-read the whole webcomic to be sure, but the only instance I recall seeing of King ending a conflict out of sheer fear was the lizard-like guy that gives up, which is also portrayed in the anime and manga.  But he didn't die, he just surrendered to avoid death. Maybe the wiki has a list of all webcomic chapters he appears in that'd aid in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short version: no, such an event is unique to the manga.

Long version:  I'm going through the webcomic looking for all of his encounters with monsters...

1. Beginning of Chapter 42: King runs into Shitanobeel, a person who transformed into a lizard-like monster over his obsession with reptiles.  Shitanobeel quickly prostrates himself and surrenders.  According to the commentary of the surrounding people, the monster cries, goes into convulsions, and passes out. In Chapter 100 we learn he's still alive.  Briefly.
2. Shortly thereafter, he encounters Dushimof, the Machine God, and later the giant bird.  He talks his away out of the first one, but neither monster is too afraid to fight him, at least during the time we see them.  King's internal monologue specifically laments that Dushimof is too strong to be scared away by his reputation alone.
3. Shortly thereafter, King's internal monologue reveals that there have been 6 prior instances where some (high-power) monster appeared before him, he closed his eyes in fear or ran away, and by the time he looked again the monster was dead.  It is strongly implied in the next chapter that Saitama was responsible for all of them (in a few cases he is manifestly so, as we can recognize the monster or even see him defeating it).  These are the events that led King to be recognized as The Strongest Man On Earth; presumably he had no substantial reputation before then, and it's not clear if the monsters in question ever even noticed him.

We don't see King encounter any other monsters until much later, around chapter 73, though he has several cameo appearances as he plays games or eats hot pot with Saitama.  This is in stuff that hasn't been covered in the anime or manga yet.

> 4. Starting in Chapter 73 he faces off against Psykos, Homeless Emperor, Evil Water, and Black Sperm at once.  All of them are very tentative about doing anything and, of course, interpret his every action as those of a supreme combat force.  Even when he runs away a few chapters later.  Psykos says that she knows very little about him, and that most monsters that encounter him simply faint. None of his opponents faint or die here.  But Psykos and Homeless Emperor get attacked by other Heroes, Evil Water does nothing because he senses no violence from King, and Black Sperm is left to face him alone (refusing to help the others because that'd leave him open to King's attack), before he also gets distracted.

King has not had any other encounters with monsters depicted in the webcomic.  So no deaths, but one went into convulsions and fainted, and there's an unreliable and unsourced rumor that many others have fainted as well.